# Host app cannot see the javadoc of my sdk

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk, javadoc

I created a small library/sdk for other apps. Devs who import my sdk cannot see comments (javadoc). What I want is that devs can see something similar like in the picture below.

Do I have to export the javadoc as a separate jar or what is the preferred way? Can this be done via Android Studio or in Gradle, ...?

[image: here you can see the javadoc of setContentView]

Comment: Have you enabled minification?

Comment: minifyEnabled is set to false